# Why when I want to delete a String from a textfile it does not work?

Tags: java

I tried to delete a string from a text file in java, but the data still remains the same.

try {

```
        //removing row from table
        mod = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        int SelectedRowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
        String day = table.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 0).toString();
        String date = table.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 1).toString();
        String venue = table.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 2).toString();
        String from = table.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 3).toString();
        String to = table.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 4).toString();
        String temp = day + "|" + date + "|" + venue + "|" + from + "|" + to;
        System.out.println(temp);
        mod.removeRow(SelectedRowIndex);

        //scanning data from file and removing data from file based on 
        //selected option in table
        File inputFile = new File("Consultation Hours.txt ");
        File tempFile = new File("Updated Consultation Hours.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
        String currentLine;

        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
            if (trimmedLine.equals(SelectedRowIndex)) {
                continue;
            }
            writer.write(currentLine + System.lineSeparator());

        }

        writer.close();
        reader.close();

        boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```

I have been finding different methods but still failed to do so, anyone knows where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are comparing a string to int, is that really your intention? Maybe you meant to compare the read line to `temp`?

Answer (score 0):

As the others explained that you are comparing the selected row index with actual text line - which makes the if condition always false. You may create an index for each line and skip the line which matches the selected row index, like below.

```java
int index = 0;
while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
    if (index++ == SelectedRowIndex)) {
        continue;
    }
    writer.write(currentLine + System.lineSeparator());
}
```